# Class Tutorial on Python.org

Tags: python, class, python-3.3

I'm going slightly mad on this one, trying with Python 3.3.0 .

On http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html there is a class example with the following code:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def add(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)
```

First I wonder that it is missing the object **class somename(object)** that Python3 normally demands.

```
class Bag(object):
```

Second, when I try to run it I get this error message:

```
>>> a=Bag
>>> a.add('23')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    a.add('23')
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

WTF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> First I wonder that it is missing the object class somename(object)
>   that Python3 normally demands.

In Python 3, your class will automatically derive from `object`, and so there's no need to do it explicitly.  The only reason this wasn't done in 2 was for backward compatibility, because so-called new-style (deriving-from-object) classes behaved slightly differently from old-style classes.

```
a=Bag
```

This doesn't make an instance of `Bag`, it just says that `a` is now a new name for the `Bag` class.  As a result, when you use

```
a.add('23')
```

you're not calling the method `add` of an instance, so the instance isn't being passed as the first argument (it can't be, as there isn't an instance yet!)  As a result, it's interpreting '23' as your value for `self`, and therefore you didn't pass an `x`, hence

```
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Try

```
>>> a = Bag()
>>> a.add('23')
>>> a.data
['23']
```

instead.